# How to convert rows data into column data in mysql by avoiding Null Values

Tags: mysql

I have table like :

```
 emp_number | leave_status | leave_length_days | leave_type_id |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+
|        775 |            3 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            3 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            3 |              0.50 | 001           |
|        775 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            2 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |           11 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |           11 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            2 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        775 |            2 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        776 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        776 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        776 |            4 |              0.00 | 001           |
|        776 |            4 |              0.00 | 001           |
|        776 |            1 |              1.00 | 001           |
|        776 |            1 |              1.00 | 001
```

And I want Output like :

```
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
| emp_number | leave_type_id | pending | approved |
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
|        775 | 001           |    4.00 |     8.00 |
|        776 | 001           |    4.00 |     NULL |
```

I have tried Below Query :

```
select emp_number
     , leave_type_id
     , (CASE WHEN leave_status=1 THEN sum(leave_length_days) END) pending
     , (CASE WHEN leave_status=2 THEN sum(leave_length_days) END) approved 
  from em_leave 
 where emp_number in (775,776) 
 group 
    by emp_number
     , leave_status
     , leave_type_id;
```

But it giving me output like :

```
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
| emp_number | leave_type_id | pending | approved |
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
|        775 | 001           |    4.00 |     NULL |
|        775 | 001           |    NULL |     8.00 |
|        775 | 001           |    NULL |     NULL |
|        775 | 001           |    NULL |     NULL |
|        776 | 001           |    4.00 |     NULL |
|        776 | 001           |    NULL |     NULL |
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
```

I don't want the NULL values. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `leave_status` from the `GROUP BY` , place the `SUM()` out side the `CASE EXPRESSION`  :

```
select emp_number
     , leave_type_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN leave_status=1 THEN leave_length_days ELSE 0 END) pending
     , SUM(CASE WHEN leave_status=2 THEN leave_length_days ELSE 0 END) approved 
  from em_leave 
 where emp_number in (775,776) 
 group by emp_number
        , leave_type_id;
```

I assume you're using MySQL as it is the only DBMS that allows this sh*t .